# Quartz+Httpclient，the job thread always be suspended without any error reports and exceptions

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, httpclient

Quartz’s version is 2.2.1 and Httpclient’s version is 4.3.1 
This is my spring configuration。

```
<bean id="downloadTaskWithIP" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="taskBO"/>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="downloadTaskWith"/>
    <property name="concurrent" value="false"/>
</bean>
<bean id="download" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="downloadTaskWithIP"/>
    <property name="cronExpression" value="25,55 * * * * ?"/>
</bean>
<bean id="startQuertz" lazy-init="false" autowire="no"
          class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
       <list>
            <ref bean="download"/>
       </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This is my taskBo：

```
public String getSource(String url, String ip) {
    try {
        String[] ipString=ip.split("[^0-9]");
        ......
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
        RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectionRequestTimeout(5000).setConnectTimeout(5000).setLocalAddress(inetAddress).build();
        httpGet.setConfig(requestConfig);
        response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        return entity != null ? EntityUtils.toString(entity,
                Charset.forName("utf8")) : null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public void downloadTaskWith(String url,String ip){
    int i=5;
    while(i--){
        getSource(url,ip);
    }
}
```

Now,the program always be suspended when my network speed is poor.

When the network speed is good,it works very well. I have three questions:

1. I have write `setConnectionRequestTimeout(5000)`,`setConnectTimeout(5000)`. Why does it still suspend the thread instead of raising an exception?
2. If I want my program work strictly according to cronExpression. In other words, if the job spend too long in this setting time, however,as long as the next setting time has come, it will stop the job and restart the job.
3. Whether because I call `httpclient.execute(httpGet)` so frequently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the socket timeout not connection time out, because connection time out used for time out if connection established( when network is down completely). What I feel is that since the network is slow/congested  data transfer might be slower. Hence you need to timeout for get/put operation.

See the socketTimeout method description

```
/**
     * Defines the socket timeout (<code>SO_TIMEOUT</code>) in milliseconds,
     * which is the timeout for waiting for data  or, put differently,
     * a maximum period inactivity between two consecutive data packets).
     * <p/>
     * A timeout value of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout.
     * A negative value is interpreted as undefined (system default).
     * <p/>
     * Default: <code>-1</code>
     */



RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectionRequestTimeout(5000).setConnectTimeout(5000).getSocketTimeout(5000).setLocalAddress(inetAddress).build();
```

From Spring batch perspective, Spring batch has no way to understand what is happening inside your method. And there is no timeout provided for step or job execution.

one way you can try is that implement Listener class for step and in the class implement before method, you can use `stepExecution.getJobExecution().stop();` after time out.